# Array in DataFrame Panda Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame. In Column ArraysDate contains many elements. I want to be able to number and run the for loop in the array of java. I have not found any solution, please tell me some ideas?.
Ex with CustomerNumber = 4 , then ArraysDate have 3 elements ,and understood i1,i2,i3,i4 to use calculations in ArraysDate.
Thanks you

```html
CustomerNumber           ArraysDate
1                         [ 1 13 ]
2                         [ 3 ]
3                         [ 0 ]
4                         [ 2 60 30 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get an array of data from 'ArraysDate' based on column 'CustomerNumber'.

Basically, you can use **loc**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'c': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'date': [[1,2],[3],[0],[2,60,30,40]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[df['c']==4, 'date']
df.loc[df['c']==4, 'date'] = df.loc[df['c']==4, 'date'].apply(lambda i: sum(i))
```

Result:

```
[2, 60, 30, 40]

   c    date
0  1  [1, 2]
1  2     [3]
2  3     [0]
3  4     132
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lambda to sum all items in the array per row.

Step 1: Create a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'ID': [[1,2,3],[1,2,43]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Step 2: Sum the items in the array

```
df['ID2']=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
df
```