# Caculator Arrays in Column DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with Arrays Column in DataFrame 
ex : I have This Data

```
CustomerNumber           ArraysDate
1                         [ 1 4 13 ]
2                         [ 3 ]
3                         [ 0 ]
4                         [ 2 60 30 40]
```

I Want caculator sum the element in ArrayDate
I create a function

```
    def Caculator(n,x,value):
        v = 0
        for i in n-x:
            v = sum(value)
        return v
```

And

```
    s['Sum'] = Caculator(s['n'],1,s['ArraysDate'])
```

n is count the element of ArraysDate Column 
And I want  caculator

```
Sum  = t1 + t2 +....+t_n-x
```

And Expect Result :

```
CustomerNumber           ArraysDate         Sum
1                         [ 1 4 13 ]         5
2                         [ 3 ]              0
3                         [ 0 ]              0
4                         [ 2 60 30 40]      92
```

Comment: Is this the same question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248375/array-in-dataframe-panda-python/56248542

Comment: Please post your expected outcome

Comment: @Chris , I added Expect Result

Comment: Sure @Arunoprayoch

Comment: @TrinhPham: Please do not use *snippet* to format code but just *code sample*. Snippet is for javascript code that can be directly executed in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
df['Sum']=df.ArraysDate.apply(lambda x: sum(x[:len(x)-1]))
#or df.ArraysDate.str[:-1].apply(sum)
print(df)
```

---

```
   CustomerNumber       ArraysDate  Sum
0               1       [1, 4, 13]    5
1               2              [3]    0
2               3              [0]    0
3               4  [2, 60, 30, 40]   92
```

*DF*: `df = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerNumber': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ArraysDate': [[1,4,13],[3],[0],[2,60,30,40]]})`

Comment: It is good , But I want add column sum_1 = t_n-x+1+..+tn. can you suggest me how to calculate sum_1

Comment: Yes , It means the sum of the elements excluding those calculated in "sum".

Comment: Yes , but with CustomerNumber = 4 , n = 4 , x = 2 . Then sum_1 = t(4-2+1) + t4 = t3+t4 = 70 . I need the general formula, with x being the number of options, it can be 1,2,3 or 4. 
sum_1 = t(n-x+1)+...+t(n-1)+tn

Comment: @TrinhPham considering n=2 can you share the expected output for all the rows? is it: `17,3,0,70` ?

Comment: Sure , It is expect result

Comment: @TrinhPham then i how working if you just flip the slicer to the other side `df.ArraysDate.apply(lambda x: sum(x[len(x)-2:]))` ?

Comment: Ok , I will check and I annouce to you , hehe

Answer (score 0):

You can make sum in ArraysDate column of Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d={'CustomerNumber':pd.Series([1,2,3,4]),
  'ArraysDate':pd.Series([[1,4,13],[3],[0],[2,60,30,40]])}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df['sum']=[np.sum(i[0:(len(i)-1)]) for i in df['ArraysDate']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   CustomerNumber       ArraysDate   sum
0               1       [1, 4, 13]   5.0
1               2              [3]   0.0
2               3              [0]   0.0
3               4  [2, 60, 30, 40]  92.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
def Caculator(x,arrayDates):
    vList = []
    for i in range(arrayDates.count()):
        v = 0
        for num in range(0, len(arrayDates[i])-x):
            v = v + arrayDates[i][num]
        vList.append(v)
    return vList
```

for the DataFrame s:

```
data = [[1, [1, 4, 13]], [2, [3]], [3, [0]], [4, [2, 60, 30, 40]]]
s = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CustomerNumber', 'ArraysDate'])
```

and call the function like this:

```
s['Sum'] = Caculator(1,s['ArraysDate'])
```